# Printing info and Error Log in separate files in Java

Tags: java, log4j

```
 log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
 # setup A1
 log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.R.Threshold=info
 log4j.appender.R.File=info.log
```

...

```
 # setup A2
 log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.R.Threshold=error
 log4j.appender.R.File=error.log
```

...
This is log4j.properties file which i am using but still log.info satatements are not printed in info.log file, while log.error is printed in error.log.

Any mistake in properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to declare rootLogger as INFO or declare specific components with INFO (ex : log4j.logger.com.myProject=INFO) foe which you want entries in info.log

Comment: Are you using logger.info in your code and setting INFO in properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You're settings two times the same appender. You need to use two appenders, e.g. `R1` and `R2`, or as the comment suggests, `A1` and `A2`) :

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, A1, A2
# setup A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.A1.File=info.log
...

# setup A2
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.Threshold=error
log4j.appender.A2.File=error.log
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply .When i used two appenders log.error printing in error.log but info.log printing log.info as well as log.error statements.I need log.info only in info.log and log.error statements only in error.log.

Comment: 1) In any case you will need two appenders. You can't log in two files with a single appender.

Comment: Agree, but what is the need of using threshold=info if still log.error get printed in error.log file.Do you know the reason?

Comment: 2) having a min level **and** a max level is not standard in log4j. For this you will need a `LevelRangeFilter` applied to your appender. See an example [here](http://bitfish.eu/java/log4j-multiple-appenders-with-different-log-levels/) (He uses xml configuration but I believe you can do the same with properties)